# Oracle 'pseduo-fact' view

Tags: oracle, optimization, view, oracle10g

Assumptions:

1. I have a number of tables comprised of facts and foreign keys ('dimensional' and 'key-value' type).  For example, ENCOUNTER:

ID - primary key

**dimensions**

- LOCATION_ID
- PATIENT_ID

**key-value**

- TYPE_ID
- STATUS_ID
- PATIENT_CLASS_ID
- DISPOSITION_ID
- ...

**facts**

- ADMISSION_DATE
- DISCHARGE_DATE
- ...

  1. I don't have the option to create a data warehouse
  2. I would like to simplify the data structure for reporting

My approach is to create a number of pseudo-dimensional views ('D_LOCATION' based on the DEPARTMENT and LOCATION tables) and pseudo-fact views ('F_ENCOUNTER' based on ENCOUNTER table).  In the pseudo-fact view, I would JOIN the key-value tables (e.g. STATUS, PATIENT_CLASS) to the fact table to include the name fields (e.g. STATUS.NAME, PATIENT_CLASS.NAME).

Questions:

- If a query selects a subset of all of the fields from F_ENCOUNTER (i.e. not all of the key-value.name fields), is the Oracle 10g optimizer smart enough to exclude some of the key-value table joins (i.e. the ones that aren't included in the query)?
- Is there anything that I can do to optimize this architecture (other than indices)
- Is there another approach?

** edit **
Goals (in order of importance):

- reduce query complexity; increase query consistency; decrease report-development time
- optimize query-processing
- minimize administrator burden
- decrease storage

Answer (score 1):

One optimization suggestion is not to use key-value pair tables. The concept of a Dimension table is that each record should contain all information about that concept without needing to join to normalized tables - i.e. turning a star schema into a snowflake schema.

While values might be repeated across dimension table records, it has the advantage of fewer joins in your reporting queries. Denormalizing tables in this way might seem counter intuitive but where performance is paramount it is usually the best solution.

Comment: I think a colleague called this a 'junk' dimension.  It was reserved for fields with low cardinality.  It certainly makes sense.  Unfortunately, this client doesn't have the appetite for data warehouse.  I suppose I could create a view that de-normalizes data in this way, then materialize it (daily).  Call it F_ENCOUNTER_JUNK.

Comment: No, junk dimensions are for combining several disparate ideas that don't need their own table (which can, itself, end up being a key-value table). It's usually named something generic, like STANDARD_VALUES. Your dimensions like PATIENT and LOCATION are legitimate dimensions in their own right.

Answer (score 0):

- I don't believe Oracle would exclude any joins done in the view, because the joins can impact the number of rows returned. (As when an inner join fails to match any rows, making the whole result set empty.)
- What are the goals of your optimization?  Query speed? query simplicity? storage efficiency?  If you can sacrifice storage efficiency for better query performance, then replace the key-value references with the values themselves (`TYPE_NAME` instead of `TYPE_ID`, `PATIENT_CLASS_NAME` instead of `PATIENT_CLASS_ID`, etc.).
- [Edit:] If the original architecture cannot be modified, consider using a materialized view.  It would essentially pre-compute the joins and store the result set, giving you speedy query time at the cost of extra storage space and possibly-not-fresh data.  You can control the latter by specifying an appropriate refresh policy.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view and http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96520/mv.htm for further details.

Comment: I don't understand your second point.  How would I 'replace the key-value references with the values themselves' in a view?  Or are you suggesting a table?

Comment: What I mean is to replace the key-value IDs in the ENCOUNTER table with the actual values, so that ENCOUNTER will contain columns such as TYPE_NAME, PATIENT_CLASS_NAME, etc.  It will probably increase the storage requirements of the table but eliminate the need for joins to key-value tables.

Comment: It's unlikely that the DBA would be willing to do this, as the table in question is one of the vendor's standard tables.  I know I could create a custom repository, but I'm trying not increase the ETL burden.

Comment: OK - I added a thought on materialized views to my answer, if that option helps.